# What complexity following algorithm has?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

What is complexity of following code?

```
public static int foo(int[] a){
        int[] b  = new int[a.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i){
            for(int j = 0; j < b.length / 100; ++j ){
                b[i] += a[i] + a[j];
            }
        }

        int result = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++ ){
            result += b[i];
        }
        return result;
   }
```

Comment: Why don't **you tell us** what you think it is (and why), and then we can correct you if you're wrong?

Comment: `O(a.length x b.length) + O(b.length)`, normaly you can just say it's `O(n^2)` if `a` is of size `n`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int foo(int[] a){
    // O(1)
    int[] b  = new int[a.length];

    // O(a.length x a .length)
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i){
        // O(a.length)
        for(int j = 0; j < b.length / 100; ++j ){
            b[i] += a[i] + a[j];
        }
    }

    // O(1)
    int result = 0;

    // O(a.length)
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++ ){
        result += b[i];
    }
    return result;
```

}

Let's say `a` is of size `n`, total: `O(n^2)` + `O(n)` = `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be:

```
O(1) + O(n)*O(n/100) + O(n) = O(1) + O(n^2/100) + O(n)
```

So overall complexity is `~O(n^2)`